# PHP Laravel manytomany eloquent distinct query

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, many-to-many

I have two tables 
Projects and Categories with a many to many relationship since a project can be beneath several Categories.

In Laravel 5.4 I have setup a manytomany relationship on the two models which uses the category_project pivot table.

I would like to retrieve all the projects beneath an array of categories.

For a single category this works fine

```
$Projects = Category::find(1)->projects()->distinct();
```

However when I pass in an array of ids to find to the find method I get an error "Method projects does not exist" which I assume is because it is returning a collection.

```
 $Projects = Category::find([1,2])->projects()->distinct();
```

Am I going about this the correct way? What do I need to do to get the projects for a list of category ids (in this example 1 and 2).

Answer (score 1):

If you want distinct projects that belong to either category 1 or 2 then it's easier to go at it the other way around e.g.

```
$categories = [1,2];
$projects = Projects::whereHas(["category" => function ($query) use ($categories) {
        return $query->whereIn("category_id",$categories);
}])->get();
```

If you want projects that belong to both categories then you can alter your condition to

```
$projects = Projects::whereHas(["category" => function ($query) use ($categories) {
     return $query->where(collect($categories)->map(function ($v) { 
          return ["category_id",$v]; 
     }));
}])->get();
```

Comment: Thanks for this... I will give this a go! Would I be able to attache pagination() on the end of the get? I'll try it... I am quite new to eloquent and the collect() and map() methods are new to me. Good time to learn what they do... Thanks again.

Comment: @user1002794 `collect` is not related to eloquent directly. It's related to [Laravel collections](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/collections) which are basically laravel's OOP/fluent replacement to arrays and are also used in the model result sets.